# Python Flow Controls Not Working

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Ok so in this I have an issue where if the answer is `"N"` then it will still continue to the `else` statement. How do I fix this? (this is all in a function, edit: with other if statements that work fine)

```
 if command == "Exit":
    exit = 1
    while exit == 1:
        print("Quit? Y/N:", end="")
        ex = input()
        if ex == "Y":
            quit()
        elif ex == "N":
            break
        else:
            print("Err")
```

Comment: Doesn't do the same for me

Comment: I wonder if you have an indenting issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Code Seems To work Fine.

I assumed what you Want to do is : on Entering Exit ask user Y or N if user enters Y you quit the program if user enters N you want to break out of while loop. It works fine for both the cases can you add something else to the question to illustrate the problem.

I would also recommend you to try using  **return statnment**  while trying to break from multiple loop or if you are creating function for this purpose.

Make sure You are not entering small alphabets . You can use .upper() function to make sure you always use uppercase.

Comment: Thank you so much, the return statement is what fixed it.